# A flush beating a full house in a hold 'em poker?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, hand-history

I'm playing with  T7 here vs Q6 suited. He gets a queen-high flush and I get a full house on the river. The game system gives him the win.

[image: screenshot from the game]

<sup>Image resized. Click for larger variant</sup>

I thought a full house beats a flush. Is this a bug?

Comment: Tough luck, I hadn't heard of a short deck (6+) holdem game before either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a 6+ NLHE game (also referred to as short deck). In this game the hand ranking are different and a flush is better than a full house. Here is a link to partypoker's short deck hand rankings: https://www.partypoker.com/en/how-to-play/short-deck-rankings. Double check the hand rankings wherever you are playing, I have also heard of short deck games where a three of a kind beats a straight but this is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Is "six plus" the same as short deck (like regular texas hold-em, but with all 2s, 3s, 4s & 5s removed from the deck)?

In that game a flush does beat a full house due to the change in relative probabilities caused by card removal.

Comment: to answer your question, yes 6+ is the same as short deck.